# how to determine the rollback cause in a cftransaction

Tags: coldfusion

I have set of inserts that are wrapped in a `<cftransaction>` block, and I am getting a error and the insert is being rolled back.

Here is the code in question stubbed for space:

```
<cffunction name="InsertTCUV" access="public">
    <cfargument name="vehicle required="true" type="xml" />

    //Parsing the xml document here

    <cftransaction>
        <cfquery name="TCUVinsert datasource="mydb">
            INSERT INTO tcuv
            VALUES(...)
        <cfquery>

        <cfquery name="qLatestTCUVID" datasource="mydb">
            SELECT TOP 1 tcuv_id FROM dbo.tcuv ORDER BY tcuv_id DESC
        </cfquery>

        <cfset curTCUVID = qLatestTCUVID.tcuv_ID>

        <cfset optionsResult = insertOptions(curTCUVID,vehicle>
        <cfset imagesResult = insertImages(curTCUVID,vehicle)>
        <cfset standardFeaturesResult = insertStandardFeatures(curTCUVID,vehicle

    </cftransaction>

</cffunction>

<cffunction name="insertOptions" access="private">
    <cfargument name="TCUVID required="true type="numeric" />
    <cfargument name="vehicleInfo" required="true" type="xml" />

    <cfset var result = "good">        

    <cftry>
        <cfset optionNode = xmlSearch(arguments.vehicleInfo[1], "p:RemarketingOption">
        <cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#arrayLen(optionNode)#">
             <cfset optionNodeNotes = XmlSearch(optionNode[#i#], "p:OptionNotes")>

             <cfset optionNotes = "">

             <cfloop index="j" from="1" to="#ArrayLen(optionNotesNodes)#">
                 <cfoutput>
                     <cfset optionNotes = optionNotes & " " & #optionNotesNodes[j].xmlText#>
                 </cfoutput>
             </cfloop>

     <cfquery name="insertOptions" datasource="mydb">
                INSERT INTO dbo.tcuv_options
        VALUES (
                    <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#arguments.TCUVID#">,
                    <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value='#xmlSearch(optionNode[i], "p:OptionID")[1].xmlText#'>,
                    <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value='#xmlSearch(optionNode[i], "p:OptionTypeCode")[1].xmlText#'>,
                    <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value='#xmlSearch(optionNode[i], "p:OptionShortDescription")[1].xmlText#'>,
                    <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#optionNotes#">
                )       
             </cfquery> 

       </cfloop>

       <cfcatch type="database">
          //dumping cfcatch.* information
          <cfset result = "error"
       </cfcatch>
   </cftry>
   <cfreturn result>
 </cffunction>
```

This whole thing is in a loop on the calling page, and everything works fine the first time through the loop.  One the second pass, the `TCUVInsert` works, but I get to the insertOptions function, a coldfusion error is thrown saying that, `variable insertOptions is undefined`, and when I get the database, the second row isn't there, which tells me there was an error and the insert rolled back.  So, there is an error with the insert of the options, and coldfusion isn't giving me the right error to diagnose it.  So either I have to look in the database logs, which apparently are not setup, or try to extract the error from the `cftransaction` block, which I'm not sure how to do.

coldfusion 9, sql server 2008 r2

Any thoughts?

Comment: I suspect the error is exactly what is happening. For some reason the `insertOptions()` function is being blown away. I'd put a `try`/`catch` around that code and dump some stuff out and start your troubleshooting from there. IE: start the troubleshooting from the POV that CF is telling you the correct thing, not that it's mistaken and you know better. Because that won't be the case. Also don't seem to be VARing your variables... all variables within functions should be VARed. It perhaps won't be part of your issue here, but if you have variables leaking out of your functions... who knows?

Comment: is this your actual code? There are a lot of syntax errors in it.

Comment: no, I should have copy and pasted, but I hate trying to line everything up

Comment: Seconded, what @MattBusche says. The code you posted is clearly an approximation of your code, not your actual code. The code you posted would never compile, let along run and give runtime errors. Pls post your *actual* code, or if you cannot for some reason, post code that you can actually (and have actually ~) run. And post the actual error messages too, just just an extract of it.

Comment: @RobM it's probably OK to put a bit of extra effort in if you're asking other people to take their time out to help you ;-) Or you could perhaps stick the code in pastebin or a Gist or something.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that retyping all of the code is faster than copy/pasting what you have already and indenting it.

Comment: I'm creating a pastebin

Comment: http://pastebin.com/XfDarscu

Comment: Image of Error: http://i.imgur.com/MAeKZra.jpg

Comment: You are overwriting the function by using the same name for a query variable ie `<cfquery name="insertOptions"`. You need to change the name to something else (or remove it since inserts do not return a resultset).  Also, do not forget to `var` scope all query names.

Comment: You should seriously re-think that 400-line function. If a function doesn't fit on one screen, it's (probably) too long. 400 lines is just crazy.

Comment: most of that function is parsing the xml document.  I could create a bunch of functions to split it up.

Comment: Well the parsing of the XML is a different function from the putting in the DB, for a start. Each function should only do one thing. So each bit you have a comment block around that deals with a different bit of the data (eg: "Vehicle Pricing Information") should be a different function too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> <cffunction name="insertOptions" access="private">
> ```

You are overwriting the function by using the same name for a query variable:

```
   <cfquery name="insertOptions" datasource="imports">
```

Interestingly it is all because the query name was not `var` scoped. Functions are stored in the `variables` scope of the component. So by failing to localize the query name, you end up overwriting the function stored in `variables.insertOptions` when you run the query. Because `insert` statements do not return a resultset, that variable ends up being undefined. Hence the error. In this case the solution is to either scope the query name, or better yet remove it entirely (since it is not populated anyway).

Just one more reason to always `var/local` scope function variables - *yes, query names too*!

Comment: Nothing to do with your error, but if you are using `SELECT TOP` to grab the record you just inserted - don't - it is **not thread safe**. Assuming your table has an identity column, use cfquery's `result` attribute to grab the generated id. Then use that value to do the lookup.

Comment: I've change it to use `theVehicle.IndentityCol`, but I don't know what "not thread safe" means.

Comment: It means if multiple requests (or threads) ran the function at the same time, some of them could end up using the wrong id. It is equivalent to using the equally flawed, `select max(...)` method. This entry is a bit dated, but has a good explanation of the issue (plus much of it still applies): http://www.iknowkungfoo.com/blog/index.cfm/2008/6/1/Please-stop-using-SELECT-MAX-id . Of course now cfquery returns the `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` value for you via the `result` attribute.